# Closing Database and Cursor WIth ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have an `onCreate()` method which uses a `datasource.open()` and `datasource.close()`. If issue `datasource.close();` at the end of `onCreate()`, my ListView SimpleCursorAdapter is always blank.

If i remove the `datasource.close();` from the end of the `onCreate()` the ListView is populated.

I cannot figure it out for the life of me why this is the case.

Anyone have any documentation as to why this happens?

Sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    id = extras.getLong("extraID");

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    datasource = new SMSDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    Cursor groupCursor = datasource.queryByGroup(long id);

    contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, // Use a template
            // that displays a
            // text view
            getCur, // Give the cursor to the list adapter
            new String[] { DBManagement.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME,
            DBManagement.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NUMBER }, // Map the NAME
            // column in the
            // people database to...
            layouts); // The "text1" view defined in
    // the XML template

    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

    registerForContextMenu(list);

    groupCursor.close();
    datasource.close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use Content Provider? By that can work with cursor.

Comment: this depends on scope of ur cursor object. post ur code 2 get proper reason..

Comment: Added code. it's the normal generic listview adapter hookup uing a simple cursor adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually manage your cursor, you should call `deactiveate()` in your activity's `onStop` and then `requery()` on resume.

However I would simply use `Activity.startManagingCursor()` which will take care of this for you. This method is marked as deprecated so if you'd like to do things exactly as Google recommends you to you'd want to use `CursorLoader` class to work with your cursor asynchronously. Frankly, unless your database is really big and/or your queries run really slow there's no harm in using deprecated method, it's not going anywhere for a while.

Comment: StartMAnagingCursor and requery and deprecated now. I use Adapter.changeCursor to replace requery.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the `datasource.close()` method call should be placed somewhere in `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy` methods..But it is not necessary
If you will post some code snippet, I could possible provide more accurate answer..

Comment: If i do that, I got the infamous `close() was never called on the cursor or database`